# $K = \mathbb C(X)[T]/(X^2-f(T))$ is purely transcendental when $f$ has a double root

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $f \in \mathbb C[T]$ be a monic polynomial of degree $3$, with $z_1,z_2,z_3$ as roots. Denote $K=\mathbb C(X)[T]/(X^2 - f(T))$.

I have to prove that if $z_1=z_2$, $K$ is purely transcendental and generated by $\frac{X}{T-z_1}$.

I was able to prove that $g(T) = X^2 -f(T) \in \mathbb C(X)[T]$ is irreducible, therefore that $[K : \mathbb C(X)]=3$ and $K/\mathbb C$ is transcendental of transcendental degree equal to $1$. So $K \simeq \{a_0 + a_1T + a_2 T^2 \mid a_0, a_1,a_2 \in \mathbb C(X)\}$. If $z_1=z_2=a$ and $z_3=b$, we have $X^2-(T-a)^2(T-b)=0$ and $T = \frac{X^2}{(T-a)^2}+b$. *But I'm not able to reach the desired conclusion...*

This is exercise 5 from those French [Galois Theory exercises](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Ejean-francois.dat/enseignement/Galois/TD24.pdf).

Comment: Write $U=X/(T-z_1)$. Your calculations seem to imply that $U^2=T-z_3$. Therefore $T\in \Bbb{C}(U)$. Why does this imply that also $X\in\Bbb{C}(U)$? Why does that imply the claim $K=\Bbb{C}(U)$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for those good questions! Indeed, if $U^2=T-z_3
$, we get  $X = U(U^2 + z_3-z_1)$ as $X=U(T-z_1)$. *I shouldn't have missed that!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [Jyrki](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen)'s comment, if we write $U = \frac{X}{T-a}$, we get

$$X = U(T-a)=U(U^2+b-a)$$ which allows to conclude.

Comment: I knew you would work this out :-)